# What to do with slow office addin?

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office

I'm developing an addin for Outlook and I don't have any experience with this.

The addin is calling some webservices to populate dropdownboxes in a ribbon and when selecting an item in a dropdown-box, the mail is sent to a webservice for processing. This all works, but it's really slow when starting Outlook and Outlook 2013 disables slow addins by default. What can I do to make startup faster? Is it possible to move the initialization to another event?

These are the highlights from the startup:

ThisAddIn.cs:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _logger.Info("ThisAddIn_Startup begin");

    CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject();

    _logger.Info("ThisAddIn_Startup end");
}

public override void BeginInit()
{
    _logger.Info("BeginInit begin");

    var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
    bootstrapper.ConfigureOutlookAddIn();
    IocContainer.Container = bootstrapper.Container;

    base.BeginInit();

    _logger.Info("BeginInit end");
}

protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    _logger.Info("CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject begin");

    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.IRibbonExtension[] ribbons = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.IRibbonExtension[] { new RibbonConnectMail() };

    _logger.Info("CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject end");

    return Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonManager(ribbons);
}
```

RibbonMail.cs:

```
private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    _logger.Info("Ribbon load begin");

    init();

    _logger.Info("Ribbon load end");
}
```

This is what is logged:

```
2013-11-19 08:34:27.0380|INFO|ThisAddIn|CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject begin
2013-11-19 08:34:28.0770|INFO|ThisAddIn|CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject end
2013-11-19 08:34:28.4982|INFO|ThisAddIn|BeginInit begin
2013-11-19 08:34:28.5543|INFO|ThisAddIn|BeginInit end
2013-11-19 08:34:32.0143|INFO|ThisAddIn|ThisAddIn_Startup begin
2013-11-19 08:34:32.0143|INFO|ThisAddIn|CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject begin
2013-11-19 08:34:32.0283|INFO|ThisAddIn|CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject end
2013-11-19 08:34:32.0283|INFO|ThisAddIn|ThisAddIn_Startup end
2013-11-19 08:34:34.2045|INFO|RibbonMail|Ribbon load begin
2013-11-19 08:34:36.4228|INFO|RibbonMail|Ribbon load end
```

What is taking so long? And what happens between these methods (f.ex the four seconds between BeginInit end and ThisAddIn_Startup begin and the two seconds between ThisAddIn_Startup end and Ribbon load begin?

**Added after Traubenfuchs answer**
I've removed NLog to see if that was the problem. I've removed the call to CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject() in ThisAddIn_StartUp (which seemingly was redundant). A DLL with shared code is still loaded and I'm using AutoFac for IoC.

After these changes, the addin loads in about 750-800 ms on my development machine. But on my testmachines it is more like 4-5 seconds.

This is what my code looks like now:

ThisAddIn.cs:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}

private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}

protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonManager(new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.IRibbonExtension[] { new RibbonMail() });
}
```

RibbonMail.cs:

```
private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        InitializeRibbon();
    }).Start();
}
```

I have even tried removing references to AutoFac and the shared DLL, comment out every line of code and removing all configurations in app.config. It still takes about 650-750 ms to start.

Any suggestions as to what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can offer you a solution in one word: Threads.
Program your addin with threads, **especially** any startup procedures and enable user interaction at the end of the startup thread. (This can be a simple global "addinReady" boolean that is checked on user interaction, a delegate (method pointer), making user elements visible, etc.

This is the easiest way to make a new thread. Think about it like parting railways...

```
new System.Threading.Thread(()=>
{
    CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject();
}).Start();
```

Another way to use Thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject);
thread.Start();
```

You might rather want to thread the init() method in RibbonMail.cs or even just selected parts of your initialization.

Comment: Thanks, that made a difference. I'm still interested in knowing any other tricks as it is still very slow starting up. How long should I expect starting up the .NET-framework takes? Can I do anything to avoid this?

Comment: On my computer a 4000 line C# program starts up in <1s. Are you sure you are struggling with .net startup performance? I believe it's probably your code that is slow. Set a breakpoint at the earliest line of code you can. As soon as it breaks there any sort of .net startup is essentially finished. To detect blocks that take to long I used the Stopwatch class to narrow down what takes up so much time and fix it. Is your Outlook startup time still affected? If done properly Outlook Addins shouldn't increase Outlook startup time by a single second.